# special characters keybd_event c++

Tags: c++, string, winapi, unicode, keyboard

I have a string with special character, like this `std::string test = "hello é -";` I want write this string with `keybd_event` but special characters wasn't good display.
I do this :

```
std::string result = "Hello é -";
int taille = result.size ();

for (int i = 0 ; i < taille ; i++)
{
    keybd_event(VkKeyScan(result.at(i)),0x9e,0 , 0);
    keybd_event(VkKeyScan(result.at(i)),0x9e, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);
}
```

I did some research and found `std::wstring` for unicode but even with that it doesn't work, any idea ?

Comment: Ask yourself how you would **type** an arbitrary character on the keyboard. Then reproduce that. Better still, us automation.

Comment: Straight from the documentation of [keybd_event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304.aspx): *"This function has been superseded. Use [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx) instead."* Sending a sequence of keystrokes that must not be interspersed with keyboard input from other sources (as is the case in your question) is the reason, why `keybd_event` has been replaced with `SendInput`.

Comment: Yes I read documentation about `SendInput` 
but I don't really understand how to send special characters to `SendInput` @IInspectable

Comment: I have found I send unicode hexa [KEYBDINPUT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646271.aspx)

Comment: @simon You don't understand what IInspectable is saying. These two issues are unrelated. You should heed this advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `SendInput()` instead of `keybd_event()`, eg:

```
std::wstring result = L"Hello é -";
int taille = result.size ();

std::vector<INPUT> inputs(taille);

for (int i = 0; i < taille; ++i)
{
    INPUT &input = inputs[i];
    input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    input.ki.wVk = 0;
    input.ki.wScan = result.at(i);
    input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
    input.ki.time = 0;
    input.ki.dwExtraInfo = GetMessageExtraInfo();
}

SendInput(inputs.size(), &inputs[0], sizeof(INPUT));
```